# Tooltip positioning inside modal components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, position, tooltip, react-tooltip

I have a bug on site, where I have a tooltip, which is mispositioned in modal windows because of the `scroll`  value caused by `overflow-y`

> Basically, I need to send the current amount of scroll there is in
>   `overflow-y` modal component, because of the modal positioning in
>   overflow, the flow of the `<ReactTooltip />` gets offset.
>
> [image]

---

As [**per this issue**](https://github.com/wwayne/react-tooltip/issues/130)

- lifting the `<ReactToolTip />` outside of the `<Modal />` does the trick
- *which as I tested in a single `<App />` works*, but this means, you have to have the `<Modal />` in the same componenet as `<ReactTooltip />`.
- Issue is, in my project, the structure is much more complicated and the components has a nested hierarchy of sometimes 4-5 components deep inside the modal.

So as soon as you are importing a component, you can't have the `<ReactTooltip />` inside the innermost component, and if you are referencing `<ReactTooltip />` in the other layer, then it doesn't know which `id` it should reference.

As demonstrated in [this live codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-noether-943m4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

As soon as you are 3 components deep, I don't know I should reference the component and in which layer it should be.

```
 -> HOC for handling state + subcomponents
   -> Modal Component
     -> Subcomponent with tooltip
```

---

Here's also the documentation for

- [`react-tooltip`](https://github.com/wwayne/react-tooltip)
- [`react-modal`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal)